# Rails 5.2 on Heroku - missing coffee_script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have been using Rails 5.2 from the `5-2-stable` branch of Rails to use ActiveStorage, now I am updating a bunch of apps to use the released version again. As mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28965) the rails versions from Github all requires `coffee_script`. Now I want to remove `coffee`.

I cannot recreate this in my local environment or on CI, but when deploying to Heroku it fails with:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- coffee_script
       /tmp/build_2b0eaffa6f7fd662e3233ac5b4de6d62/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
```

I cannot find any mention of coffee in my code.

Could this be a caching issue on Herkou or similar? Any clues are welcome.

### Failing gemfile

https://github.com/fsek/voting/blob/50d063d16ae8d323f0cfe57e5bb6b4299c592019/Gemfile

### Working gemfile (separate project, can be deployed)

https://github.com/pensionsupplysning/web/blob/cb256668640e38af4b59e8cf23fbfa939728abb7/Gemfile

Answer (score 1):

Add the gem `coffee-rails` to your project or migrate to sprockets 4.x and make sure you follow this migration guide: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#manifestjs

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the problem I had was that I wanted to remove `coffee-rails` completely. It is however no longer a problem.